# Why Let Docker Choose a Port

Tags: docker

What is the use-case for letting docker choose a port range automatically with the -P flag?

Is this just convenience so that you don't have to explicitly pass a specific port? But then any thing needing to access that service would need to know the port right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far use-case this is very important to let the docker choose port automatically in some cases like blue-green deployment on a single host.

For Instance, You running your container on AWS ECS and there is one EC2 instance so you would not able to do a blue-green deployment, in this, you will get an error something like

> service test was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 97d97ce9-967d-49ad-83ad-f4f904aae1f6 is already using a port required by your task. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.

You can also look into this article,

> If you have a service with 2 containers (tasks), you need at least 2 ECS container instances because multiple containers can’t run on the same port on the same server, each container is hosted on a separate server. So in order to run multiple containers over the same container instance, we need Dynamic port mapping!

This is in the context of AWS, you can replicate in your case as well by deploying multiple services on your host using dynamic port mapping.

[understanding-dynamic-port-mapping-in-amazon-ecs-with-application-load-balancer](https://medium.com/@mohitshrestha02/understanding-dynamic-port-mapping-in-amazon-ecs-with-application-load-balancer-bf705ee0ca8e)

This is one case, another case can be, you would able to run multiple services of the same docker container because all need the same port, which can be achieved using the dynamic port.

Another case can be the Wowza streaming engine which needs a dynamic port or range of port to publish and get the stream from the client.

Dynamic port mapping explains here in case of AWS.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/